# How to open lod clamp specified in shader in glsl?

Tags: glsl, vulkan, amd

amd instruction set spec said:

```
IMAGE_SAMPLE_D_CL_O SAMPLE_O, with LOD clamp specified in shader, with user derivatives.
IMAGE_SAMPLE_D_CL sample texture map, with LOD clamp specified in shader, with user derivatives.
IMAGE_SAMPLE_D sample texture map, with user derivatives
IMAGE_SAMPLE_CL sample texture map, with LOD clamp specified in shader.
```

in vulkan, i use textureGrad in glsl.
Running on radeon, i got a image_sample_d in asm

How to get image_sapmle_d_cl in vulkan or opengl?

In other words， how to open LOD clamp specified in shader, as the spec said.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's supported by AMD, but there is [ARB_sparse_texture_clamp](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_sparse_texture_clamp.txt) which adds `textureGradClampARB` in addition to the sparse samplers it adds.

Comment: Ok,thanks. I have got this instrucion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vandench‘s comment solved this:

> I'm not sure if it's supported by AMD, but there is [ARB_sparse_texture_clamp](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_sparse_texture_clamp.txt) which adds `textureGradClampARB` in addition to the sparse samplers it adds.